# session security in php and things to look out for

Tags: php, security, session

This has been asked a bunch of times. I am just curious as to if it is believe that the below code provides a fairly signicant level of security. are there other if's i should think about?

a few assumptions:

1. if user does nothing in 5 seconds, log him out.
2. if user is not coming from somePage.php log him out.
3. if users ip address changes, log him out.

code below:

```
<?php
session_start();
$time = time();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($time - $_SESSION['time'] > 5)
{
    //function to log out user...//echo "logged Out,Time";
}
elseif ($ip !== $_SESSION['ip'])
{
    //function to log out user...//echo "logged out,IP";
}
elseif ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== "http://server.com/somePage.php")
{
    //function to log out user...//echo "logged out,Refer";
}
else
{
   //do sensitive stuff
}
$_SESSION['time'] = $time;
$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
```

EDIT:

This is just some basic stuff in the "sensitive" area. on maybe a facebook level.  I dont want anyone to get into who shouldn't be. but if they did, there would be some problems, but  nuclear missles will not be launched.

5 seconds was my example for testing, clearly it would be longer.

Bryan,

if $_SERVER can be spoofed, are there better methods to ascertain the user's source ip?

Comment: Security requirements vary with context, based on factors like the type of application, the types of information that the application collects, and any laws pertaining thereunto. So, without some context from you it's nearly impossible to tell you whether your security measures are necessary or sufficient for your application.

Comment: Also, FYI, almost any $_SERVER variable can be spoofed by an attacker.

Comment: Yup, "sensitive stuff" means nothing - both logging visitor info and launching a nuclear missile fall in this category. You have to be more specific what you're going to do so we can tell you what level of security is suitable.

Comment: _“if user does nothing in 5 seconds, log him out”_ – yeah, those nasty buggers that might actually try to _read_ something for more than five seconds … those have no place in our modern ADHD society, so kick ’em! (Sorry if this comment deserves a TL;DR from your point of view.)

Comment: For what it's worth, even Google lets you switch IPs and keep your session active.  Consider rotating the session ID with every request so you don't have to worry about this so much.

Answer (score 1):

> a few assumptions:
>
> 1. if user does nothing in 5 seconds, log him out.
> 2. if user is not coming from somePage.php log him out.
> 3. if users ip address changes, log him out.

You will drive your users (whom are probably not exclusively male) insane. Especially Tor users.

The number of things you have to do to implement [secure PHP sessions](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions) is small:

1. Use a CSPRNG to generate session IDs.
2. Use HTTPS.
3. Use HttpOnly cookies (so they're invisible to JavaScript).
4. Use Secure cookies (so they're only available in HTTPS).
5. Use `session_regenerate_id(true);` whenever a user logs in or out before assigning new session variable values.